# Want to display sub tests under respective parent tests using php

Tags: php, mysql, nested-loops, recordset

I am a php newbie and want to know the looping code which will display the sub tests under their respective parent tests using php and mysql. Please see the images. I want to show the tests in following manner / layout and all the tests are coming from database table.

[image: This is how I want the tests to show. Please check Differential Leukocyte Count and Widal Agglutination Reaction and sub tests under both of these.]

Here is the database structure and a screenshot of few of the records from the database.
[image: Tests mysql database table]

Few test records

[image: Database records]

Note: I am only having sub tests for 1st level. So my requirement is only for the 1st sub level.

I would appreciate if sub one helps me with the code to fetch and the records from the database and display it. I am totally confused and stressed with it. Any little help will do wonders for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `parent_id` = 0");

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   echo $result[test_name];
   $child_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `parent_id` = $result[id]");

   while($child = mysql_fetch_array($child_query)) {
       echo $child[test_name];
   }
}
```

if you want with 1 query it could be sth like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`");
$results = array();

while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $results[] = $result;
}

$tmps = $results;

foreach($results as $result) {
    echo $result[test_name];
    foreach($tmps as $tmp) {
       if($tmp[parent_id] == $result[id])
            echo $tmp[test_name];
    }
}
```

this might have some errors but the approach i think would be something like that

Comment: Thanks for the answer but cant you help me using a single mysql query and handling the child query part using an array. I think that can save the database load and page load time will also be faster. Thanks though for instant help. I appreciate it.